# Redux: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: redux

I'm hard fighting with Redux, trying to dispatch `inputValue` to a store. When I'm trying to do this I get `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` error.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './SearchingBar.css'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import actions from '../../duck/actions'


  const SearchingBar = ({shareToggleClass, props}) => {

    const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    const search = event => {
        if(event.key === "Enter") {
            setToggleClass(true);
            shareToggleClass({toggleClass})
            props.add(query)
        }
    }
    return (
        <input type = "text"
          placeholder = "Search.."
          className = {toggleClass ? "Active" : "unActive"}
          onChange = {e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value = {query}
          onKeyPress = {search}
        />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  inputValue: state.inputValue
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addValue: inputValue => dispatch(actions.addValue(inputValue))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchingBar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your component argument destructuring is wrong.

Currently, you have:

```js
const SearchingBar = ({shareToggleClass, props}) => {
```

However, as written, this assumes that the one-and-only argument for this function, which is an object we normally refer to as `props`, *also* has a nested field named `props`.  That's probably not correct.

If you're trying to grab out just the `shareToggleClass` field, and then access all remaining props field as an object named `props`, you should use "rest destructuring":

```js
// The ... rest operator grabs all remaining fields, and puts them in a new object
const SearchingBar = ({shareToggleClass, ...props}) => {
```

Alternately, you could just destructure any remaining fields specifically that you need:

```js
const SearchingBar = ({shareToggleClass, add}) => {
```

The other issue is that you likely don't have a `props.add` function anyway, because your `mapDispatch` is configured to create a prop named `addValue`:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addValue: inputValue => dispatch(actions.addValue(inputValue))
})
```

Also got a couple suggestions on the React-Redux usage.

If you are going to use `connect`, [we recommend using the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) instead of writing it as a function:

```js
const mapDispatch = {
  addValue: actions.addValue
}
connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent)

// or even just pass the `actions` object directly
connect(mapState, actions)(MyComponent)
```

But, [we specifically recommend using the React-Redux hooks API as the default instead of `connect`](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-redux-with-react):

```js
const SearchingBar = () => {
    const inputValue = useSelector(state => state.inputValue);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    const search = event => {
        if(event.key === "Enter") {
            setToggleClass(true);
            shareToggleClass({toggleClass})
            dispatch(addValue(query))
        }
    }
    return (
        <input type = "text"
          placeholder = "Search.."
          className = {toggleClass ? "Active" : "unActive"}
          onChange = {e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value = {query}
          onKeyPress = {search}
        />
    )
}
```